# Simulate reopening documents at app launch

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

For purposes of both debugging and automated testing, how do I simulate launching an application with the last open document(s) automatically reopened? Does it work exactly the same as simply launching the app with a set of documents for it to open, such as with `NSWorkspace.open(_, withApplicationAt:, ···)`? (In my experiments that doesn't seem to be the case.)

I'm having an issue where my document window isn't getting initialized properly in that reopen case, so I want to make sure I'm recreating the scenario correctly.

(At first I was confused because I couldn't get state restoration to happen at all. Finally I realized I had "Close windows when quitting an app" turned on in System Preferences, which disables state restoration.)

Comment: You have to code the restore methods yourself.

Comment: Which "restore methods"? The bug in my app is a recent one; reopening used to work fine with no special effort on my part. Is there a flaw in the built in behavior that I need to override and fix?

Comment: I see. In Xcode, under edit Scheme, Run, then Options, you can select "Persistent State" to choose restoration or non restoration on launch. You can check what you have set.

Comment: "Launch application without state restoration" is not checked.

Comment: Turns out part of my problem was I had "Close windows when quitting an app" turned on in System Preferences. I'd still love to be able to simulate state restoration for tests, though.

Comment: I don't think you can. Apple's state restoration framework is very opaque and context sensitive. I spent quit a bit of time trying to reuse it so that my normal open and restore code was the same and it simply doesn't work. Invoking the state restoration methods yourself, outside of the normal app start up, will crash deep inside Cocoa...

Comment: OK, thanks. It looks like I'll have to set it up by quitting the app with a document open so the system will handle it for me. I suspect the bug I saw was due to corrupted restoration data, so I may just have to wait and see if that happens again.